# How to hide a popup by clicking outside

Tags: jquery

I am trying to come up with a way so that once #email-popup or #phone-popup is visible, if the user clicks anywhere EXCEPT the visible popup, then it is going to hide the popup.

My method for hiding the popups in the code below does not work well...

My JQuery so far

```
$(".email").click(function(){
    $("#email-popup").show("fast");
});
$(".phone").click(function(){
   $("#phone-popup").show();
});

$(document).click(function() {
     $("#email-popup").hide("fast");                        
     $("#phone-popup").hide("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're close - just stop the propagation when the user clicks within the popups:

```
$("#email-popup, #phone-popup").on("click", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$(".email").on("click", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $("#email-popup").show("fast");
});

$(".phone").on("click", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $("#phone-popup").show();
});
```

Also you have some repeated code in the document click. You're hiding the email popup twice.

```
$(document).on("click", function() {
  $("#email-popup, #phone-popup").hide("fast");
});
```

Comment: @MHZ Yes it does - this is basic jQuery. Please show me how you've implemented it.

Comment: @MHZ You need to stop propagation on the `.email` and `.phone` as well.

Comment: its not working for me:( idk why.. I just copied and pasted the code, it looks like it should work, the popups appear but never disappear when I click elsewhere...

Comment: Which popup are you trying it with? Your document click only hides `email-popup`.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the ID of the element clicked (won't work on children of the elements) :

```
$(".email").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#email-popup").show("fast");
});
$(".phone").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#phone-popup").show("fast");
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
     if (!(e.target.id === 'email-popup' || e.target.id === 'phone-popup')) {
         $("#email-popup, #phone-popup").hide("fast");                        
     }
});
```

[**DEMONSTRATION**](http://jsfiddle.net/u6ECV/)

Comment: this does not work, it acts the same way as it did with the code posted above, popup just appears and disappears instantly... thanks though

Comment: you should modify your comment to match your jquery from fiddle, your solution on jfiddle worked for me! but the one posted above did not :) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What about it doesn't work well?  What does happen?  By the way, you're hiding `#email-popup` twice in your `click` handler.

Comment: the popup appears and disappears instantly.

Comment: @JMM This is more of a comment than an answer.