# How to make this area display: none?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a web application. First see this image:

[image]

Now, you can see the area outlined by yellow line. The list with white background is dynamic (It is displayed when something is typed in search bar). Now what I want is when I **click anywhere out of this area** (Search input field + List), the **list** should be `display: none`. I've tried a few things but for that I had to write a lot of code as I did this for different divs separately.

Also, I don't want to paste the whole code here as it is too long. So I'm just providing you HTML to get an idea of this picture.

```
<header>
    <div id="headerdiv">
        <div class="headerlogo"><a href="/passwords/home.php"><img src="#" alt="Passwords"></a></div>
        <div class="quit"><img src="#" alt="Quit"></div>
    </div>
</header>
<div id="functions">
    <div id="funcLeft">
        <div id="addbuttonwrap"><input class="addbutton" type="button" value="  +              ADD"></div>
        <div class="heading1">Your saved passwords</div>
        <input class="funcbutton" type="button" value="EMAIL">
        <input class="funcbutton" type="button" value="CAREER">
        <input class="funcbutton" type="button" value="SOCIAL">
        <input class="funcbutton" type="button" value="OTHER">
    </div>
    <div id="funcRight">
        <div id="search">
            <form name="searchform" method="post" action="">
                <input type="text" name="searchinput" placeholder="Enter any keyword">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="heading1 heading2">GUIDELINES</div>
        <div class="slides">
            <!--CONTENT-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    <div id="footer">
        Copyright: Protected
    </div>
</footer>
```

NOTE: While writing answer, you can assume any TAG Name/class/ID etc. for any element as code is not sufficient. I just want to know what to do.

Comment: it's hard to say. Can you provide link to site or jsfiddle?

Comment: If you know many sites have this functionality. e.g. Facebook. How do they do it?

Comment: please provide the code .,or find the clicked element on the body , decide on it

Comment: I think you can solve it in the similar way we do for popups. For Ex : We show a popup based on a button click or something and when the user clicks outside the popup, the popup disappears. 
Please check the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666179/how-to-hide-a-popup-by-clicking-outside

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide the search when someone clicks away, you can do this with Javascript with a `onclick` event.

```
var elementToHide = document.getElementById("searchElement");
window.onclick = function(e){
    if(e.target != elementToHide){
        elementToHide.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

This will hide the element contained in `elementToHide` (can be any element in the DOM) when the user clicks on an element which is *not* this one.

The variable `e` contains the click event of which we check the target element in the if

Hope it helps

Comment: This will also hide the list when I will click the search bar, which is not intended.

Comment: You can simply change the `elementToHide` variable to have what you want to act as a search element (or wrap the whole search elements in a container and target that container)

Comment: Not working doesn't mean much, what code did you use and what do you get in console?

Comment: This comparison is not valid I think. I tried this: $(document).click(function(event){
  var $click=$(event.target);
  var $click2=$("#search input");
  if(event.target===$click2){
   //$("#suggestions").css("display", "none");
   console.log("hello");
  }
 });

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if(e.target.className != "search_element"){
       $("#element_list").hide();
    }
 });
```

you can try this.

Comment: This does not answer his problem, it will hide the element wherever the user clicks (even if the user clicks on the search element)

Comment: how if add condition for some elements?

Comment: How do I write if statement if my search element is a div (#search) and inside it is a form with an input?

Comment: you can add class for every preventive element from close "#element_list", example (#search,#form_serach,#input_search) add class "search_element"

Comment: The comparison is not working. To test it, I did this: $(document).click(function(event){
  var $click=$(event.target);
  var $click2=$("#search input");
  if(event.target===$click2){
   //$("#suggestions").css("display", "none");
   console.log("hello");
  }
 });

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for a js free solution (or easiest approach). I would personally recommend using **+** and **:focus** operator from css

```
.search-with-submenu{
  .submenu{
    display: none;
  }
  input[type=search]:focus + .submenu{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: in case you have concern about browser compatibility
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors#Browser_compatibility