# How to hide a popup by clicking outside using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are so many questions like my one,even I go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666179/how-to-hide-a-popup-by-clicking-outside) link also.But I didnt get a proper solution yet.So Im posting my issue here.

I have to popup a message when click an icon and when I click the same div where the icon is reside,it should disappear. This is working fine.But when I click outside the div also, the popup should disappear.How can I modify this javascript function to achieve it

```
<div>
<h5 class="haead">Search for a product title
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction5()"> <img class="qnicon" src="question.png">
<span class="popuptext" id="myPopup5">Search product.</span>
</div>
</h5>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction5() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup5");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");

}
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element

Comment: The other question you linked to has an accepted answer that would work for you. It basically states that on click of your dialog you need to stopPropagation which would prevent the click from bubbling up to the document and then on the document add a click handler that hides the popup.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I've found that avoids any number of other problems you could encounter, is to put the popup on top of a 100% width/height div. That "disabler" div has the same click handler as the button that would ordinarily close the popup. So if the user clicks the "X" to close, the "Ok" button (or whatever you've got set up) or the area outside the popup, same effect, it closes.

That "disabler" div (it effectively disables the entire app except for the popup) can be completely clear, or translucent, by setting the opacity.

You put the "disabler" div at z = 9998, the popup at z = 9999 (just more CSS), and they'll always be on top. Note that this may not be necessary if all your content loads into a div that is already underneath the disabler (e.g. the router-outlet div in Angular), but I usually do it anyway.

Complete basic example. I typically make a component out of this and hook it into an event bus so I can pass data in and out of it (so I can change the position, style, messages, even what happens when you click the close button). If you get this code you should be able to use some approximation of it in any framework, etc.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

.button {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: green;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    color: white;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.disabler {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99998;
    background-color: #000000;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.popup {
    position: relative;
    /* Center with whatever voodoo you like */
    top: calc(50% - 150px);
    left: calc(50% - 150px);
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    z-index: 99999;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="button" onclick="togglePopup ( )">
    Show Popup
</div>

<div class="button" onclick="showAlert ( )">
    Show Alert
</div>

<!-- This div is on top of everything except the popup div -->
<!-- It effectively disables the entire app except for the popup -->
<div id="disabler" class="disabler" onclick="togglePopup ( )"></div>

<!-- This div holds the popup -->
<!-- You can only close the popup by clicking the close button, or the disabler background -->
<!-- Clicking in the blue popup area doesn't do anything (intentionally) -->
<!-- Even though you can see other widgets through the disabler, they're all inaccessible -->
<!-- Try the show alert button to confirm -->
<div id="popup" class="popup">
    <div class="button" onclick="togglePopup ( )">
            Close Popup
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    togglePopup ( ); // Hide them to start.
    function togglePopup ( ) {
        let disabler = document.getElementById ( 'disabler' );
        disabler.style.display = disabler.style.display ? '' : 'none';

        let popup = document.getElementById ( 'popup' );
        popup.style.display = popup.style.display ? '' : 'none';
    }

    function showAlert ( ) {
        alert ( 'Hey there!' );
    }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.But I didn't get your answer. What is "disabler" div?

Comment: I'll post an example.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the way to do this:

**Javascript**

```
popup.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
// This is important to prevent the popup from inheriting the event since it 
// is inside the body

    e.stopPropagation();
});

var body = document.body;
body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(popup.classList.contains('show')) {
        popup.classList.remove("show");
    }
);
```

I wish this solves your problem

**Edit**
That didn't work because you have to structure your code properly like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id='popup-container'>
    <!-- This all inside the popup -->
    <h5 class="haead">Search for a product title</h5>
    <div class="popup-data">
        <img class="qnicon" src="question.png">
        <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup5">Search product.</span>
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="show-popup">Show Popup</a>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var popupContainer = document.getElementById('popup-container');
var body = document.body;
var showPopup = document.getElementById('show-popup');

showPopup.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    popupContainer.classList.add('show');
});

popupContainer.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if(popupContainer.classList.contains('show'))
        popupContainer.classList.remove('show');
);
```

Comment: The code is working fine, Something else in your code structure is not working, If you want to test my code you can write inside the event-listener function of the body something like this: console.log('it works') and you'll see that the function works fine..